# Copy/Paste a row (duplicate an object) in the same attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

When editing in QGIS in some shape attribute tables I can copy/paste a row with data, but in some shapes when I do this it adds NULL data rows, I know there is a solution but I failed to find out or to find here. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will answer myself. After some experiments it seems to be a QGIS bug, after restarting a project the issue fixes itself.